# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in angular js script

Tags: angularjs

I'm going crazy...I have the following angular js code:

```
(function(){
'use strict';
 angular
.module('app.core')
  .controller('inserisciController', inserisciController);


function inserisciController($http, dataService,$window){
    var vm=this;
    vm.formData={};
    // vm.formData.country="";
    // vm.formData.cfiscaleCalc="autogenerated_cfiscale";
    // vm.formData.cfiscale="";

    vm.formats = ['dd-MM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    vm.format = vm.formats[0];
    vm.open = function($event) {
        vm.status.opened = true;
    };
    vm.status = {
        opened: false
    };
    vm.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yyyy'",
        'show-weeks' : false
    };

    vm.sesso=function sesso(m, f){
        if (m) {
            vm.formData.gender="M";
        }
        else if (f) {
            vm.formData.gender="F";
        }
        return vm.formData.gender;
    };

    vm.riduciJson=function riduciJson(citta){
          vm.formData.birthplace=vm.formData.birthplace.Denom_Italiana
    };

    vm.confermaCF=function confermaCF(){
        vm.formData.codice_fiscale=vm.formData.cfiscaleCalc;
    };

    vm.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) {
        var birth=new Date(birthday);
        var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birth.getTime();
        var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

    };

    vm.estraiData= function estraiData(birthday){
        mm=birth.getMonth();
        dd=birth.getDate();
        mm=mm+1;
        yy=birth.getUTCFullYear();
        dd=dd+"/";
        mm=mm+"/";
        data=dd+mm+yy;
        return data;
    };

    $http.get('assets/bower_components/countries/countries.minimal.json').then(function(res){
        vm.countries=res.data;
    });

    // $http.get('assets/bower_components/countries/province.json').then(function(res){
    //     vm.prov=res.data;
    // });
    vm.cities = dataService.getCities();

    vm.submitForm = function(isValid) {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
          //$window.alert(vm.formData);
            // console.log(vm.formData);
            vm.ins=dataService.sendPatient(vm.formData);
            // console.log(vm.ins);
            //$state.go('paziente')
          };
       };
    };
 })();
```

and in any broswer I get caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. I'm using Atom on a Mac Os and the script has been copied by a old windows version. I tryied to find illegal caracters with hex Fiend but i found nithing. Can someone help me?

This is wath i get inspecting in firefox
(function(){
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.core')
      .controller('inserisciController', inserisciController);

```
function inserisciController($http, dataService,$window){
var vm=this;
vm.formData={};
// vm.formData.country="";
// vm.formData.cfiscaleCalc="autogenerated_cfiscale";
// vm.formData.cfiscale="";

vm.formats = ['dd-MM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
vm.format = vm.formats[0];
vm.open = function($event) {
    vm.status.opened = true;
};
vm.status = {
    opened: false
};
vm.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yyyy'",
    'show-weeks' : false
};

vm.sesso=function sesso(m, f){
    if (m) {
    vm.formData.gender="M";
    }
    else if (f) {
    vm.formData.gender="F";
    }
    return vm.formData.gender;
};

vm.riduciJson=function riduciJson(citta){
      vm.formData.birthplace=vm.formData.birthplace.Denom_Italiana
};

vm.confermaCF=function confermaCF(){
    vm.formData.codice_fiscale=vm.formData.cfiscaleCalc;
};

vm.calculateAge = function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birth=new Date(birthday);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birth.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

};

vm.estraiData= function estraiData(birthday){
    mm=birth.getMonth();
    dd=birth.getDate();
    mm=mm+1;
    yy=birth.getUTCFullYear();
    dd=dd+"/";
    mm=mm+"/";
    data=dd+mm+yy;
    return data;
};

$http.get('assets/bower_components/countries/countries.minimal.json').then(function(res){
    vm.countries=res.data;
});

// $http.get('assets/bower_components/countries/province.json').then(function(res){
//     vm.prov=res.data;
// });
vm.cities = dataService.getCities();

vm.submitForm = function(isValid) {

    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
      //$window.alert(vm.formData);
    // console.log(vm.formData);
    vm.ins=dataService.sendPatient(vm.formData);
    // console.log(vm.ins);
    //$state.go('paziente')
      };
   };
```

};
})();
������������������������

the strange is that the � character is added whenever i change the code

Comment: On what line? Is it in this JS?

Comment: Check that assets/bower_components/countries/countries.minimal.json returns a correct JSON.

Comment: seems that when i edit my file the � is added at the end

Comment: this appen only when i work on a nginx server...if i work on my local server (lite-server) all work done

Comment: inserisciController.$inject = ['$http', 'dataService', '$window'];  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/master/assets/above-the-fold-1.png